# How to update Cache from multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, caching

I have a Runnable which has a cache (of type [Cache](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html)) and we assume that it offers thread safe operations. This Runnable object is used by multiple threads.

Our threads get objects from outer source and then

1. check if the object key **exists** in the cache
2. If not, then **put**
3. If it's already in the cache then **update**

I'm looking for the right scheme (i.e. minimal `synchronized` code) to work with the cache, reliably.

I came up with the following scheme:

```
    MyObject current = cache.getIfPresent(givenKey);
    if (current == null) {
        MyObject prev = cache.asMap().putIfAbsent(givenKey, givenObj);
        if (prev == null) {
            // successful put in cache
            return givenObj;
        }
    }

    // current != null or another thread update
    synchronized (current) {
        return update(current, givenObj); // in place change of current
    }
```

The key ideas behind my scheme + "proof" of reliability:

1. If threads work on different keys then no need to block
2. If `current` is `null`, then since the cache is thread-safe, exactly one thread will be able to put the object in the cache whilst the others will see `prev != null`
3. The other threads must update serially. Notice I'm syncing on `current`, the object to be updated.

---

**Questions**

1. Is my scheme reliable?
2. Can be optimised?
3. In some cases, `volatile` must be used to make the memory synchronization reliable. Do I need it here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) no your schema is not reliable
You should not call

```
cache.asMap().putIfAbsent(givenKey, givenObj);
```

by guava documentation method cache.get(K key, Callable loader) is preferable than to use asMap methods.

2) yes it can be optimised
You should call instead this method:

```
cache.get(K key, Callable<? extends V> loader)
```

This method will return the value if already in cache, or it will add the value from the loader into the cache if the value is not in the cache and returns it.

so for example:

```
 MyObject objInCache =  cache.get(givenKey, ()->givenObj)

if(!objInCache.equals(givenobj)){
 //obje was in the cache,
//update object
}
```

3)you don't need volatile if the cache is thread safe

Comment: by the way, could you elaborate more about the third point? I do know from the docs of Guava that the cache is thread safe. Is that implicitly mean that it inherently solves memory issues as well?

Comment: As you can see, one of my operations updates the object. Would it go directly to the main memory?

Comment: Thread safe cache means that you can write and read values from cache from different threads. In your case you are storing mutable objects in the cache, so its your responsibility to make this object threadSafe, for example all methods on that object can be synchronized.

Comment: Okay, so as you can see from my code I'm using `synchronized` on the object from the cache (`objInCache` in your code), and I read that `synchronized` acts as a "memory barrier" which means it flushes to main memory.

Comment: Yes, but you have to synchronized it than for any method call on that object, not only for update.

Comment: (1) is reliable and does modify the cache directly. It is a view in that the conceptual model is a cache, not a map. However the technical design is a map decorated with a `Cache` interface.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. check if the object key exists in the cache
> 2. If not, then put
> 3. If it's already in the cache then update

This can be accomplished using the `Map` view's [compute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method.

```
cache.asMap().compute(givenKey, (key, oldValue) -> {
  return (oldValue == null)
      ? create(key)
      : update(current, oldValue);
});
```

This is thread-safe and should allow for concurrent computations of different keys. If the returned new value is `null` then the mapping is removed, else it is established / updated.

Unfortunately this is not optimized in Guava, since it was scaffolded on when adding Java 8 compatibility for its additions. You should prefer `27.0.1` or newer as there were some nasty bugs.

[Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) is a Java 8 rewrite that is designed for this feature. It builds upon lessons learned from Guava (similar interfaces, but revisits some design choices), modern algorithm research, and ecosystem improvements. Both are excellent, but you may find Caffeine is better suited for more advanced scenarios.

Comment: Ben, I read some caveat regarding `asMap()` (which I didn't completely understand).   Can you explain why I can safely use `asMap().compute()`?

https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#inserted-directly

Comment: That was written pre-Java 8, when `Map` lacked compute methods. It's still correct in that `automatically loaded` means implicit outside of your actions, e.g. `Map.get` won't call the `CacheLoader` behind the scenes. The `Map.compute` would be a manual load. Also note that while `Map.compute` defaults as not atomic, the implementation in `ConcurrentHashMap` and the caches are.

Comment: I didn't quite get the sentence " It's still correct in that automatically loaded means implicit outside of your actions", but if I understand correctly, you mean that even though the `compute` call is thread safe, inside it, we won't be able to use the `CacheLoader`. Should it be a concern? I mean, the `compute` function is atomic from the outside so we're making sort of a transaction. Should we care that it was done "manually"? (I hope my interpretation makes sense to you)

Comment: and one more question please, is `asMap()` costly in terms of time or memory?

Comment: @yaseco I meant the cache will not call the cache loader for you in the map view. That’s what you would expect. You cannot directly write into the cache in the compute methods, which is also disallowed by [Concurrent]HashMap. The view is free as the cache implements map and just returns itself.

Comment: thanks. By the way, isn't `cache.asMap().merge` more suitable?

Comment: You're right, didn't notice that you had `givenObj` and didn't compute it.

Comment: one last question, just to be 100% sure. When you run `compute` on some key, you're guaranteed that this particular key is locked (i.e. if other thread will try to `get` the same key, it will be blocked). Is that correct?

Comment: @yaseco you are guaranteed that any other write is blocked (`put`, `remove`, `compute`). A read (like `Map.get`, `Map.containsKey`) is not blocked. This would mean that `Cache.get` shouldn't block if it can read a value and will block if it has to wait for the value to materialize. If you wanted to block reads, you would have emulate a write using a computation that returns the old value.